# click on child with TestCafe

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, web-testing

I need a very simple help about click on testCafe.

I' ve got a simple  element with 10

inside. I have to click the first one or the last one or a random li from index 0 to index 10.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [nth(index)](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors.html#nth) method to select an element by its index:

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

const ul = Selector('ul');
const li = ul.find('li');

const liCount = await li.count;
const index = getRandomInt(0, liCount);

await t.click(li.nth(index));
```